# Uncaught TypeError: FormData constructor: Argument 1 does not implement interface HTMLFormElement

Tags: javascript, html

I created a event listener for a form  that is supposed to add a name of a owner to a dropdown I created in my HTML as I submit my form data. Well when I submit the form data I get a "Uncaught TypeError: FormData constructor: Argument 1 does not implement interface HTMLFormElement." when I submit.

As far as my current code....

```
      <form id = "owner_form">
        <div>
          <label for='name'>Owner Name:</label>
          <input type='text' id='name' name='name' placeholder="John Doe" required/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for='phone_number'>Phone Number:</label>
          <input type='text' id='phone_number' name='phone_number' placeholder="John Doe" required/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for='real_estate_agent'>Listing Agent:</label>
          <input type='text' id='real_estate_agent' name='real_estate_agent' placeholder="John Doe" required/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type='submit' id='owner_submit' value='Submit'/>
        </div>
      </form>


const ownerForm = document.getElementById('owner_form')
const ownerBtn = document.getElementById('owner_submit')

ownerBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  ownerForm.addEventListener('submit', (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()
    let formData = new FormData(this)
    fetch(OWNERS_URL,{
      method: 'POST',
      header: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          "Accept": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    }).then(resp => resp.json()).then((owner_data) => {
      dropdown.add(owner_data.name)
    })
  })
})
```

I need some help in determining why I am get the error message that I previously mentioned and how to resolve it in this case.

Comment: Arrow functions have no explicit `this`. In code shown `this` is probably `window` and if it's not it is definitely not the form element you are expecting

Comment: `let formData = new FormData(ownerForm)` should work.

Comment: or replace `this` with [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

Comment: And I don't get why you wrap the `submit` handler with a `click` on the button... It looks overkill.

Comment: I used that little modification you guys suggested, and  I get this message now "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: HTMLSelectElement.add: Argument 1 could not be converted to any of: HTMLOptionElement, HTMLOptGroupElement."

Comment: @Stitch: The argument you are passing to formData has to be the form element... Try console logging what you are passing to it.

Comment: When I tried to conole.log() my response I get nothing in the console. I did eliminate that embedded event listener btw

Comment: I was referencing my developer tool and when I check network info it. My post request is not even appearing.